# How to convert a dictionary to dataframe in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a dictionary:
`data_dict = {'t1': '1', 't2': '2', 't3': '3'}` into a dataframe:

```
key   |   value|
----------------
t1          1
t2          2
t3          3
```

To do that, I tried:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("key", StringType(), True), StructField("value", StringType(), True)])
ddf = spark.createDataFrame(data_dict, schema)
```

But I got the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 748, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 413, in _createFromLocal
    data = list(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 730, in prepare
    verify_func(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1389, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1377, in verify_struct
    % (obj, type(obj))))
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 't1' in type <class 'str'>
```

So I tried this without specifying any schema but just the column datatypes:
`ddf = spark.createDataFrame(data_dict, StringType()` & `ddf = spark.createDataFrame(data_dict, StringType(), StringType())`

But both result in a dataframe with one column which is key of the dictionary as below:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|t1   |
|t2   |
|t3   |
+-----+
```

Could anyone let me know how to convert a dictionary into a spark dataframe in PySpark ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `data_dict.items()` to list key/value pairs:

```
spark.createDataFrame(data_dict.items()).show()
```

Which prints

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
| t1|  1|
| t2|  2|
| t3|  3|
+---+---+
```

Of course, you can specify your schema:

```
spark.createDataFrame(data_dict.items(), 
                      schema=StructType(fields=[
                          StructField("key", StringType()), 
                          StructField("value", StringType())])).show()
```

Resulting in

```
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
| t1|    1|
| t2|    2|
| t3|    3|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Imagine if the values of the Dict are Lists as for example:  data_dict = {'t1': [1, 5], 't2': [4, 7], 't3': [8, 9]},  how can I create a DataFrame that instead of having one column with the values  of the lists,  have two columns with the values of the lists:  
+---+-----+-----+
|key|value1|value2|
+---+-----+-----+
| t1|    1|    5|
| t2|    4|    7|
| t3|    8|    9|
+---+-----+-----+

Comment: @Lucho a year late but I had the same issue, I added the solution I have found in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that if you have a dictionary that has pair `col: list[vals]`

for instance:

```
{
 "col1" : [1,2,3],
 "col2" : ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

A possible solution is:

```
columns = list(raw_data.keys())
data = [[*vals] for vals in zip(*raw_data.values())]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

But I'm new to pyspark, I guess there is even a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of dictionaries, like that:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                        {"deptId": 1, "age": 40},
                        {"deptId": 2, "age" 50},
                       ])
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

considering `data` as dict:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  data=np.array(list(data.values())).T.tolist(),
  schema=list(data.keys())
)
```